# Deleting all photos in iCloud

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, photos, photos.app

I want to delete all my photos from my iCloud (ca. 2500 Photos), so that I have no photos in the iCloud.

I have gone into my iPhone's Photo app and selected all 2500 Photos and deleted them. Then I deleted them from the "recently deleted" album in the Photos app. It said that this would delete them from all devices connected to my iCloud.

Now, my iPhone's Photos app is absolutely empty, which is what I wanted.

However, 24 hours later, on my other iOS devices, as well as on iCloud.com (accessed through my laptop), the Photos are still visible, even though it says "Updated".

Does it just take some time for the deletion of all photos to sync to all iOS devices/iCloud.com, or is something not working as I expect it to work?

Answer (score 1):

It could take several hours to delete photos from iCloud. You're deleting 2500 photos so it could take more than 24 hours to delete them depending on when you've plugged your iPhone into power and connected it to wifi.

You are aware that once these photos are deleted they're gone for good (unless you have another backup somewhere) and you can't get them back?

Comment: Also some photos wont be removed if they weren't on iCloud to begin with.

Comment: @MelvinJefferson I'm not sure what you're saying here. The OP stated "I want to delete all my photos from iCloud" which means they are **all** in iCloud.

Comment: I meant his device, the iPhone. Some photos may not be uploaded from his iPhone.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your input. Yes, I know there is no way of getting the photos back once they have been deleted from the iCloud, unless of course, I backed them up onto my Laptop's HD, which i did :)  The whole purpose of this exercise for me was to clean my iCloud from unnecessary photos und duplicates, which i did with the copy on my HD. Now i want to re-upload this local copy back to the iCloud, but for that, afaik, I should first entirely delete the photos ON the icloud. Unfortunetely, however, 48ish hours later, iCloud.com is still showing ALL the photos.. why?